# Execute Immediate for hsqldb

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

I have an HSQL 2.x database with a stored procedure. This procedure generates a dynamic SQL string that I want to execute. On Oracle I do this with the *execute immediate* command. I am having a hard time finding the equivalent for HSQLDB. Could someone please help out?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve? If you are calling HSQL through some program e.g. Java then you may want to construct the query in java side and run it. That should be fine?

Comment: The application is supposed to work against different DBMS flavors. The stored procedure is executing a bulk synchronize job (that cannot rely on hibernate). Thus, constructing the SQL within Java is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

HSQLDB does not have direct support for dynamic SQL within SQL/PSM language routines.

The way to do this is to execute the SQL string with a Java stored procedure called from the SQL stored procedure.

The Java stored procedure has a String (VARCHAR) argument, which is the SQL statement. It uses the `jdbc:default:connection` to create a JDBC Statement and execute the SQL passed in the String argument.

The SQL procedure may look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SQL_SP( ... ) LANGUAGE SQL ... BEGIN ATOMIC
  DECLARE SQL_STRING VARCHAR(1000);
  -- sql is generated here

    CALL JAVA_SP(SQL_STRING);    
  END
```